# Is there any hidden meaning behind Travis and the prosthetic arm?

Tags: plot-explanation, dexter

In the last episode of Dexter season 6 (S06E12), Travis finds the prosthetic arm

> that Louis sent to Dexter

He's seen wondering what it is, puzzled:

[image]

But quickly after that he put the arm back in the box when interrupted.

Since the arm isn't just "small detail" like the cereals he ate or shirt he wore while visiting Dexter's house, I am wondering if there is any meaning for this short scene, e.g. leading him to perform some actions later which he wouldn't have done otherwise?

Comment: I'm not sure what it means "in-universe" for Travis himself, but "out of universe" (a reason for why it was written at all) it connects back to Brian and the concept of "prostetic limbs" -- so It's thematic and maybe a little bit of callback allowing Travis to juxtapose Dexter when he is first sent something in a box. It's curious because someone does make an appearence in a season seve episode and this could feed into the changes Dexter is going through on his way to becoming "a real boy".

Comment: Also Musaka I think once called it, "The holiest of Holies"--so again kind of a sacrid artifact/mythology point in the Dexter universe. It's kind something that just doesn't go away--even the ending Dexter, deaspite the changes Dexter made, he still ends up not in controll of his life--It's like some bad joke that no matter what he does, he can't do what he wants/really be happy! The universe won't let him!